# How to show the image when it is in the div whose overflow is hidden?

Tags: html, css

I created a div and set it as overflow -> hidden and put a image in it. Now image is not displaying. Is there anyway to display the image in that div only?

Answer (score 0):

The overflow hidden means only that everytime that is to large to be displayed in the div gets not displayed completely. If you have not set the size of the div it will have the size 0x0 so nothing can get displayed. You will probably have to enlarge the div, so that it's big enough for the image.

Comment: Did you set the height?

Comment: yes. I set the height and width of div and image both. My image height and div is less then div height.

Comment: Ok. Is it than possible for you to update the code your question, so that everything related and probably important is included?

Comment: I created a div and set it as overflow -> hidden and put a image in it. Now I want to display half of  image inside the div and half of image out side of div . Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define a size (height and width) to a div unless you want to determine his exact size.
The problem might be loading the image.
Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
     div.hidden {
        overflow: hidden;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="hidden">
     <img src="someImage.jpg" alt="some image" >
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the src attribute to your image path.
If you cannot load for some reason (error in source file or slow connection), the attribute "alt" will be shown instead, meaning your code is correct but you have a problem with the source or network

Answer (score 0):

Ok than you can try to add another div around the div with overflow hidden and set the images position to absolute.

So that your markup looks like following:

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="with-overflow-hidden">
       some other elements

       <img />
   </div>
</div>
```

This should than be added in CSS

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Maybe this example can help you:http://jsfiddle.net/kv0bLpw8/